# Understanding the use of slice in function arguments

Tags: javascript

I was reading this piece of code from the mozilla developer network:

```
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

The line inside the function confused me, why can i use `call` without specifying an object to serve as `this`?

If the `arguments` is the `this` is this case, then i'm not passing any parameter to the `slice` function, right?

If i put some random element as `this` i get an empty array, like this:

```
return Array.prototype.slice.call([], arguments);
```

I know i misunderstood something, but what? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a common way to convert *array-like* objects to real arrays.

Comment: Indeed it is, my problem was with slice, now i know i can pass nothing to the function. ;)

Comment: @FelixKling I think the OP knows that, since the JS snippet is from the MDC docs on doing exactly that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like

Comment: @Matt: Just wanted to make sure everyone knows :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the arguments is the `this` is this case

...which it is

> then i'm not passing any parameter to the slice function, right?

correct.

Comment: Damn.. now i understand.. and thanks for editing the question. :) My problem was with slice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`slice` returns a copy of the entire array when called with no arguments

```
> x = [1, 2, 3]
> x.slice()
[1, 2, 3]
> x.slice() == x
false
```

In your example, this is done to convert the `arguments` pseudo-array into a true array.